# Terminal log file

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Does it exist log file where system store history of typed commands in Ubuntu 12.04 terminal? Where is it located? Could someone share a link where I can find some info about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using bash: `~/.bash_history`

Comment: Thanks, a lot.Are there the history of all opened terminals or only some of them?

Comment: I am not using bash anymore, but if I remember this right, there is a small problem with using more terminals: Each terminal makes a copy of the history-file when it's opened, appends it's commands to it's local copy of the file, and when it's closed again, it writes it's local (modified) copy back. However, if two terminals are opened simultaniously, the commands of one of them are lost. Look here for more info and solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `history` command and then searching using grep.  I.e. `history | grep ls`